# javascript determining if a day is beyond 2 days

Tags: javascript, date

i have a requirement where i only get the name of the day. like what i am doing on friday.

i want to determine if the asked day is beyond 2 days. for example, like today is tuesday. and if someone ask what i am doing on friday. then friday is the 3rd day from today.

in javascript i could see i can do data operation like

```
var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
schDate = tomorrow.toDateString();
```

but how do i find if the asked by just day name is beyond 2 days or not?

Comment: What do you mean by `beyond`?

Comment: You will never be able to determine date from only day name.It's impossible.

Comment: "now plus 24 hours" isn't always tomorrow... Example: 00:30 on the day Daylight Savings ends, will be 23:30 on the same day.

Comment: loop from `today` to `today + 2 days` checking the day name of each day, seeing if it matches the one you were given

Answer (score 1):

```
var daysArr = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var today = new Date().getDay();

//return if day difference is bigger than 2
function dayDiff(day){
    if(Math.abs(daysArr.indexOf(day) - today) > 2){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

dayDiff("Wednesday");
```

Comment: javascript mon is the first day. so index of mon is  1. and hence sun should be the first elemement?

Comment: it still wont work though. take today's example. if u ask for mon then today = 2. index of mon = 1.  the result will be a negative number.  not sure if u tried

Comment: That's why I use Math.abs() which will return absolute value (positive number)

Comment: Did you solve it? I tested the code and works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: dont remember but i found issues with this code. probably asking about mon on wed fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().getDay();
```

The `getDay` function will return the number of the day.
Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.

That means `Wednesday = 3` and `Friday = 5` 
however when it is `Saturday = 6` the next 2 days will be 0 and 1 .

Answer (score 0):

If you only get day name:

```js
    let days = {
        'sunday' : 0,
        'monday' : 1,
        'tuesday' : 2,
        'wednesday' : 3,
        'thursday' : 4,
        'friday' : 5,
        'saturday' : 6,
    }
    
    function distanceDays(from, to){
        let date = to;
        if(date < from) date += 7;
        return Math.abs(today - date);
    }

    let date = days['sunday'];
    let today = (new Date).getDay();
    
    console.log(distanceDays(today, date));
```